# .cod installed on device using Javaloader, but can't find the app on device

Tags: blackberry, ant, blackberry-jde

I'm loading my blackberry cod onto my USB connected BB Curve using the following :

```
/Users/JElsey/Development/tools/eclipse/plugins/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43/components/bin/javaloader -u load ./bin/SmartConf-BB/SmartConf-BB.cod 

RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
Copyright 2001-2010 Research In Motion Limited
Connected                 
Loading ./bin/SmartConf-BB/SmartConf-BBDone                    
1479568 bytes sent at ~1315171 bps
Disconnected
```

I can verify the transfer was correct by running `javaloader -u dir` and seeing my app listed as :

```
SmartConf$2dBB                                 0.0              1479568   Wed Sep 26 10:02:15 2012
```

However I can't actually see the app on the device anywhere.

1. It is not listed under the applications menu
2. Can't see anything under Options > 3rd Part Apps (not sure if it
   should be there or not)
3. Connected to Desktop Manager I can't see it listed in apps.

Subsequently, I'm not able to install the app via Desktop Manager, when I attempt to install it all files (.cod, .alx etc) are non-selectable, not sure if this could be an issue here.

For additional info, I'm building my .cod file with the following ant task:

```
<target name="client-bb">
        <property name="jde.home" location="/Users/JElsey/Development/tools/eclipse/plugins/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43/components/" />
        <property name="bb.src" location="/Users/JElsey/Development/projects/internal/SmartHelper/SmartConf/apps/SmartConf/blackberry/native/"/>
        <taskdef resource="bb-ant-defs.xml">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="./build-config/bb-ant-tools.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <mkdir dir="./bin/SmartConf-BB"/>
        <rapc 
            srcdir="${bb.src}" 
            jdehome="${jde.home}" 
            destdir="./bin/SmartConf-BB/"
            output="SmartConf-BB"
        />
    </target>
```

Any suggestions as to why the cod file appears to be loaded, but can't be located on the device?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually surprised that `bb-ant-tools` task doesn't fail. It should :) Check logs maybe it is but you need to add `failonerror` property.

You need `jdp` nested node in `rapc` node. Check please [documentation](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs) of bb-ant-tools for parameters